# Show $H$ is a subspace of$M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H = \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a && c \\
d && a
\end{pmatrix}\;:\;\; a,b,d \in \Bbb R\right\}$ $\subset{M_{2\times 2}} \mathbb (R)$

Show $H$ is a subspace of $M_{2\times 2} $ under the usual operations.
What are the matrices $M_1,M_2,M_3$ such that $H=\mbox{Span}(M_1,M_2,M_3)?$

So showing that it contains the zero vector is trivial. Now to show that its closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
H=span\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\}.
$$
We have
$$
aM_1+cM_2+dM_3=\begin{pmatrix} a & c \cr d & a \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, this was great! This has clarified a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The only special structure here is that the diagonal entries $(a,a)$ are the same. If I add two matrices of this type, I end up with a matrix whose diagonal elements are also the same:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 \\
c_1 & a_1
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
a_2 & b_2 \\
c_2 & a_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1+a_2 & b_1+b_2 \\
c_1+c_2 & a_1+a_2
\end{bmatrix}\in H$$

The same logic holds for scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do this, It seemed deceivingly simple. With multiplication, multiplying by a real scalar shows that it is closed also, is that enough? Its easier because we are looking at ALL real entries?

Comment: It also works for matrices with complex entries

Comment: @Clovers Yes, if you were not allowing $a,c,d$ to be any real numbers, then you would not get a real vector space